# An Inequality Involved Exponentials and Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I need help with the following problem.

> For $k,x, n > 0$ such that $k + x < n$, prove that $$\left ( \frac{n-k-x}{n-x} \right )^x \leq \binom{n-x}{k} \binom{n}{k}^{-1}.$$

I've tried using various bounds such as $e^{-t} > 1-t > e^{-t - t^2/2}$, the standard bounds for binomial coefficients, etc.

Any solutions/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you are not satisfied with my answer. That's fine, but just curious. Is my answer wrong? or Is there something unclear? Can you comment so that maybe I could improve my answer to help you?

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for! I just haven't had the chance the look at it until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS of your inequality can be written as
$$\begin{align}\frac{(n-x)!}{k!(n-x-k)!}\cdot\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}
&=\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-x-k)!}\div \frac{n!}{(n-x)!}
\\\\&=\frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)\cdots (n-x-k+1)}{n(n-1)\cdots (n-x+1)}
\\\\&=\frac{n-k}{n}\times \frac{n-k-1}{n-1}\times\cdots\times \frac{n-x-k+1}{n-x+1}
\\\\&=\prod_{j=1}^{x}\frac{n-k-j+1}{n-j+1}\end{align}$$

So, your inequality is equivalent to
$$\left ( \frac{n-k-x}{n-x} \right )^x \leq \prod_{j=1}^{x}\frac{n-k-j+1}{n-j+1}\tag1$$

In order to prove that $(1)$ holds, it is sufficient to prove that
$$\frac{n-k-x}{n-x}\leq \frac{n-k-j+1}{n-j+1}\tag2$$
holds for every $j$ such that $1\le j\le x$.

We see that
$$\begin{align}(2)&\iff (n-k-x)(n-j+1)\leq (n-x)(n-k-j+1)
\\\\&\iff j\le x+1\end{align}$$
which holds for every $j$ such that $1\le j\le x$.

Hence, we see that your inequality holds.